# A question about modified Newton’s Method on convex function

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For a modified Newton’s Method, it simplify means multiplying a step size constant with the newton's direction such that
\begin{equation}
x_{k+1} = x_k -t_k \left(\nabla^2 f(x_k)\right)^{-1} \nabla f(x_k)
\end{equation}
So, for this modified Newton’s Method with a twice continuous differentiable function satisfying strong convexity condition $MI\succcurlyeq \nabla^2 f(x)\succcurlyeq mI$. If we suppose $\{x_k\}$ is the sequence generated by this modified Newton’s Method with step length $t_k = m/M$,  I want to prove that the following inequility hold:

\begin{align*}
f(x_k)  - f(x_{k+1}) \geq \frac{m}{2M} \nabla f(x_k)^T (\nabla^2 f(x_k))^{-1}\nabla f(x_k)
\end{align*}
What I have tried is directly substitute $x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{m}{M}\left(\nabla^2 f(x_k)\right)^{-1} \nabla f(x_k)$ into the quadric expansion of $f(x)$:
\begin{align*}
f(x_{k+1}) &= f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T (x_{k+1} - x_{k}) + \frac{1}{2}(x_{k+1} - x_{k})^T \nabla f(x_k) (x_{k+1} - x_{k})\\
&\leq  f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T (x_{k+1} - x_{k}) + \frac{M}{2}\|x_{k+1} - x_{k}\|^2\\
& = f(x_k) - \frac{m}{M}\nabla f(x_k)^T (\nabla^2 f(x_{k}))^{-1}\nabla f(x_{k})) + \frac{M}{2} \frac{m^2}{M^2}\|\nabla^2 f(x_{k}))^{-1}\nabla f(x_{k})\|^2\\
&\leq f(x_k) - \frac{m}{L}\nabla f(x_k)^T (\nabla^2 f(x_{k}))^{-1}\nabla f(x_{k})) + \frac{M}{2} \frac{m^2}{M^2}\|\nabla^2 f(x_{k}))^{-1}\|^2 \|\nabla f(x_{k})\|^2\\
\end{align*}
Since the matrix 2 norm is just the largest eigen value and the eigenvalue of $(\nabla^2 f(x))^-1$ is equal to $1/\sigma(\nabla^2 f(x))$.

Then, use property $m \leq\sigma_{min}(\nabla^2 f(x))$ we have

$$\sigma_{max}((\nabla^2 f(x))^{-1})\leq \frac{1}{m} $$
\begin{align*}
f(x_{k+1})& \leq f(x_k) - \frac{m}{L}\nabla f(x_k)^T (\nabla^2 f(x_{k}))^{-1}\nabla f(x_{k})) + \frac{m^2}{2L} \frac{1}{m^2} \|\nabla f(x_{k})\|^2\\
& = f(x_k) - \frac{m}{L}\nabla f(x_k)^T (\nabla^2 f(x_{k}))^{-1}\nabla f(x_k)) + \frac{1}{2M}  \|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2\\
\end{align*}

Then, I am stacking at here , can anyone help one how could I go further to get the result? I think I am missing something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stop one step earlier and use that
$$
\|v\|^2=v^TIv\le\frac1mv^T(∇^2f(x_k))v
$$
and apply that to $v=(∇^2f(x_k))^{-1}∇f(x_k)$ to get
$$
m\|(∇^2f(x_k))^{-1}∇f(x_k)\|^2\le ∇f(x_k)^T(∇^2f(x_k))^{-1}∇f(x_k).
$$